# Why is my CSS behaving this way?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a shopping site for an assignment and having trouble with my index CSS3.

1. My second section (background of "Open Link") is not behaving as a block but as a full page. For example my picture is only partially viewable and the rest is hidden below
2. My "Open Link" button is flawed, I'm currently unable to add any sort of design to it as it messes with the section it is in (EG boxes don't work, they just bug out
3. Am I even creating the layout I want the correct way?

```css
body{
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     font-family: tahoma;
    }
    
    ul{
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #363377;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
     
    }
    
    #design-top{
     width: 100%;
     height: 40%;
     *background-color: #575594;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
     
     background-image: url(../img/bg2.jpg);
     background-size: cover;
     background-size: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     
    }
    
    #design-bottom{
     background-color: #333;
     height: 56%;
    }
    
    #startbtn{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
    }
    
    span{
     display: block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     padding-top: 150px;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    #left{
     float: left;
     border-right:solid 1px #fff;
    }
    
    #right{
     float: right;
    }
    
    li a{
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #left:hover, #right:hover{
     background-color: #555;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/js.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <ul>
   <li id="left"><a href="#home">Company</a></li>
   <li id="left"><a href="#home">Sales</a></li>
   <li id="left"><a href="#home">About</a></li>
   <li id="left"><a href="#home">Contact</a></li>
   <li id="right"><a href="">Cart</a></li>
   <li id="right"><a href=""><?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?></a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div id="design-top">
  
   <span><a href="" id="startbtn"><h1>Open Store</h1></a></span>
  
  </div>
  
  <div id="design-bottom">
   
  </div>
 
 </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you make the js fiddle or paste here your complete code that we can review and answer correctly

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8m5m8627/2/ i tried, basically the link for "open store" is suppose to be in the middle, under the colour box where the link is updated is suppose to be another colour :/

Comment: In terms of your image overflow being hidden, it's hard to tell without specifically seeing the issue. But I think it's due to `background-image: cover` which will scale your image but cut off if it's too big for the container. Try using 'contain' instead or alternatively increase the size of your containing div.

Comment: Its because you used <h1> tag for "open store" which applied padding values to that element. Try removing h1 tag add custom class with div or span tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So is it you are looking for vertically centering the `open store` text. If so, you can do it like this.

I've marked the changes in the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/8m5m8627/3/

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #363377;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#design-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px; /*40%;*/
  background-color: #575594;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background-image: url(../img/bg2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: table; /*added*/
}

#design-bottom {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 56%;
}

#startbtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

span {
  /*display: block;*/
  /*padding-top: 150px;*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell; /*added*/
}

#left {
  float: left;
  border-right: solid 1px #fff;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#design-top h1 { /*added*/
  margin: 0;
}

#left:hover,
#right:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/js.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <ul>
      <li id="left"><a href="#home">Company</a></li>
      <li id="left"><a href="#home">Sales</a></li>
      <li id="left"><a href="#home">About</a></li>
      <li id="left"><a href="#home">Contact</a></li>
      <li id="right"><a href="">Cart</a></li>
      <li id="right">
        <a href="">
          <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="design-top">
      <span><a href="" id="startbtn"><h1>Open Store</h1></a></span>
    </div>

    <div id="design-bottom">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```